# Adding a shape to class properties

Tags: java, swing, awt, shapes

I am working on a game which has a class Player, there are 3 subclasses of player. These are different types of players who have different methods and variables. Anyhow I want to give each player a different look. I would like to start really basic for now, I'm thinking a rectangle for one player, circle for another and a triangle for the other.

What I am wondering is how am I best to implement this? Iv thought about adding a method for each player which draws a different shape using the paint Component. I don't think this is correct though as I a particular shape should be a property of the player not just a method (I think) Is there a way for me to declare a shape for each player and then call on that shape in my GUI and draw it there....

I could add my class code to this example but I don't think it would help much with the question..

Any insight would be much appreciated!!!

Thanks!

Comment: Thinking is not enough. Write some code as well. If you run into errors then post your code with your query.

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right this will be good design for you

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
public class MyShape { //this could be your Player 

    protected Shape shape;

    draw(Shape shape){
        // code to draw shape go here
    }
}

class MyRectangle extends MyShape { // this could be your Rectangle_Player_type
    // Initilization Block runs before constructor
    {
        shape = new Rectangle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry My mistake, My first classes were in upper but they conflicted with java standards names as Rectangle and Shape so I wrote it Quickly to test it and forget to change

Comment: thanks for the reply YouYou. Can I then go onto call on shape from an independent method and draw what ever shape it is ?